# Need Help to Converting Delphi Time to .Net Time

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, datetime

I am porting a Delphi application to C# and I've run into a problem. The Delphi app records the time into a log file, which then gets read back into the program. But the format of the time it records confuses me. I can find no .Net library to convert it properly.

Delphi recorded time in log file: 976129709 
(this gets converted to 1/14/2009 5:53:26 PM in the Delphi code)

```
//Here is the Delphi code which records it: 
IntToStr(DirInfo.Time);

//Here is the Delphi code which reads it back in:
DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(StrToInt(stringTime));
```

Anybody have any ideas how I can read this in .Net?

Comment: Why was this downvoted. Is there a simple solution that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delphi's TSearchRec.Time format is the old DOS 32-bit date/time value. As far as I know there's no built-in converter for it, so you'll have to write one. For example:

```
public static DateTime DosDateToDateTime(int DosDate)
{
     Int16 Hi = (Int16)((DosDate & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
     Int16 Lo = (Int16)(DosDate & 0x0000FFFF);

     return new DateTime(((Hi & 0x3F00) >> 9) + 1980, (Hi & 0xE0) >> 5, Hi & 0x1F,
        (Lo & 0xF800) >> 11, (Lo & 0x7E0) >> 5, (Lo & 0x1F) * 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it when I get a chance. Sounds like this might be the solution.

Comment: I did a quick test in a console app, and this seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: The format of the dos filetime is described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724274(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hi. I found this very useful. How would you go about converting a System.DateTime to a 32 bit DosDate? Thanks!

Comment: @Matt, you'd have to follow that spec that VolkerK provided and pack DateTime into a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @Jon. Thanks. I made another post regarding the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895382/net-datetime-to-dos-date-32-bit-conversion

Comment: An alternative method that would allow you to do this would be to convert the datetime variable into a string variable and then use this string variable to build a new datetime variable. You can then use this to go both ways.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is description of different date/time formats](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx) (Delphi's native TDateTime is OLE Automation date format).
According to this, you need [System.DateTime.FromFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx) and [System.DateTime.ToFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx) + [DosDateTimeToFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724247(VS.85).aspx) and [FileTimeToDosDateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724274(VS.85).aspx) functions.
Actually, this is conversion in two-steps.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both googling and experimenting, starting with dummy code to find something similar to the unix epoch.

```
  var x = 976129709;
  var target = new DateTime(2009, 1, 14, 17, 53, 26);
  var testTicks = target.AddTicks(-x);     // 2009-01-14 17:51:48
  var testMs = target.AddMilliseconds(-x); // 2009-01-03 10:44:36
  var testS = target.AddSeconds(-x);       // 1978-02-08 22:44:57
  // No need to check for bigger time units
  // since your input indicates second precision.
```

Could you verify that your input is correct?

And for the love of the Flying Spaghetti Monster, abandon your 12 hour time format! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Will do. I still have to make work retroactively however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game, but I've been using this for several years, and it works great. It converts the Delphi time to Windows ticks, which get converted to a DateTime.

```cs
public static DateTime DelphiTimeToDateTime(this double delphiTime)
{
    // scale it to 100nsec ticks.  Yes, we could do this as one expression
    // but this makes it a lot easier to read.

    // delphitime *= 864000000000L

    delphiTime *= 24; // hours since Delphi epoch
    delphiTime *= 60; // minutes since epoch
    delphiTime *= 60; // seconds since epoch
    delphiTime *= 1000; // milliseconds since epoch
    delphiTime *= 1000; // microseconds since epoch
    delphiTime *= 10; // 100 nsec ticks since epoch

    // Now, delphiTime is the number of ticks since 1899/12/30

    long time = 599264352000000000L; // 1/1/0001 --> 1899/12/30

    time += (long)delphiTime;

    // These are all *local* times, sadly
    return new DateTime(time, DateTimeKind.Local);
}
```